# Icon inside textbox - almost like glyphicon icon

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I've got a textbox in which I need to add a Symbol. This symbol should always be visible and not be used in code behind (when getting the value of the textbox) - basicall like a glymphicon icon. I've tried using a span but it is not displaying the way it should.

This is what I've done:

```
    <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon"><b>$</b></i></span>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AgreedValue, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Agreed Value" })                                
    </div>
```

This is how it's currently being displayed:

[image]

And this is what I need it to display like:

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing? or how can I get it to look like the 2nd image?

Answer (score 1):

Its all about style, If Html can be changed, then this is my solution:

```css
.input-group {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
}

.input-text {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.input-text:focus {
outline: none;
}
.input-group {
padding-left: 10px;
width: 300px;
height: 40px;
border: 1.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="input-group">
         <div>
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon"><b>$</b></i></span>
         </div>
         <input type="text" class="input-text">                               
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately html cannot be changed and the css for the input group cannot be changed either as this is a general textbox style for all accross the application....